# Code to move two images to the middle

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I am inserting 4 images in LaTeX with the code below. However, the images in the top row have a different size than the images in the lower row.

I do not want to make the toprow figures smaller with `[width=0.8\textwidth]`. But I want to move the figures in the same horizontal row more to each other (to the middle). So the  A simple visual explaination below:

x --->   <--- x

I only could not find the code to do this. Help is much appreciated!

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
 \begin{center}
\hspace*{-3.5cm}
    \subfigure[]{%
        \label{elderly}
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{Elderly2.png}
    }%
    \subfigure[]{%
       \label{ethnicity}
       \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{Ethnicity2.png}
    }\\ %  ------- End of the first row ----------------------%
   \hspace*{-3.5cm}
    \subfigure[]{%
        \label{statusscore}
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{Statusscore2.png}
    }%
    \subfigure[]{%
        \label{sports}
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{sports2.png}
    }%
\end{center}

\caption{%
    The geographic spread of the variables used in the different models.
 }%
\label{fig:subfigures}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Try: (1) replace `\begin{center}` with `\centering` and omit `\end{center}`, (2) between sub figures put `\hfil`,  (3) omit `\hspace*{-3.5cm}`, (4) instead `\subfigure` use `subfloat` from package `subfig` or `\begin{subfigure}[]{<width>} ... \end{subfigure}` from pasckage `subcaption` etc. And on the end not the last, always provide complete minimal document starting with `\documentclass{...} ` follows with necessary packages, `\begin{document}` your code snippet and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Zarko shouldn't this be an _answer_?

Comment: @AFeldman, almost, however, I (we) don't know nothing about actual picture, which OP use. I guess, that she/he probably have problems with white border around them. Shortly, I will make an answer ... (very soon).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From you code I observe:

- you probably use deprecated package `subfigure` which is directly replaced with `subfig`. Beside it there is also very powerful `subcaption`
- your image together have width 1,6 text width, this is not possible to put in one row without to locally extend place for figures for 60% ..., for this the use of `\hspace*{3.5cm}` is not the best solution.
- ...

Assuming, that your document is one column article, that you are willing to replace your `subfigure` with `subfig` and use `example-image` from package `graphicx`, I obtain the following result:

[image]

Above picture is generated with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
\subfloat[]{%
        \label{elderly}
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    }\hfil
\subfloat[]{%
       \label{ethnicity}
       \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    } %  ------- End of the first row ----------------------%

\subfloat[]{%
        \label{statusscore}
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    }\hfil
\subfloat[]{%
        \label{sports}
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    }%
\caption{%
    The geographic spread of the variables used in the different models.
 }%
\label{fig:subfigures}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

From code you can observe, that the with of pictures is limited to `0.45\textwidth`. If this is not accetable in you like to have wider pictures, than one way to do this is use package `changepage` and its macro `adjustwidth`. In this case in preamlbe add

```
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
```

and content of figure enclose in for example in

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{-3cm}{-3cm}
< subimages >
\end{adjustwidth}
```

An example:

[image]

where I also add package show frame, that you can see page layout. Complete code for this picture is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-3cm}{-3cm}
\centering
\subfloat[]{%
        \label{elderly}
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    }\hfil
\subfloat[]{%
       \label{ethnicity}
       \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    } %  ------- End of the first row ----------------------%

\subfloat[]{%
        \label{statusscore}
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    }\hfil
\subfloat[]{%
        \label{sports}
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    }%
\caption{%
    The geographic spread of the variables used in the different models.
 }%
\label{fig:subfigures}
\end{adjustwidth}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If you can not reproduce this result with your original images means, that they have white border around images. To be sure in this, try to enclose it in

```
`\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{<your image>}}
```

to see this.